# Does Lagom support REST only?

Tags: lagom

I know this is an odd question... after all, why would anyone use SOAP these days?  But I would like to build a proof of concept and I need to produce a SOAP service. It's not apparent to me how that might be done in Lagom but from the documentation it appears to be very much focused on REST so it doesn't look like a good choice for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Lagom supports REST and WebSockets, and it's not likely that SOAP support will be added in future.